# how can get data-url for the last of my click

Tags: javascript, html

I have three `a` tags with `data-url` and class `data-click`. I click on it many times.

When I click on `#log` I want `console.log` to show my last clicked `data-url` not all of my clicked `data-url`

```js
$('.data-click').on('click', function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  var dataUrl = btn.attr('data-url');
  document.getElementById('log').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(dataUrl)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-url="1" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>
<a data-url="2" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>
<a data-url="3" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>

<a href="#!" id="log">log</a>
```

Comment: Why are you adding a _new_ click handler to your #log element, each time one of those `.data-click` links gets clicked ...?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting event handlers is generally something to avoid. In this case it will repeatedly add a new click handle to `#log`, which is why you see **all** previous values output to the console.

To do what you require you can place a class on the `.data-click` element, removing it from previously clicked elements. Then in the `#log` click handler you can select the `.active` element and read the `data-url` from it.

```js
let $a = $('.data-click').on('click', function() {
  $a.removeClass('active');  
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#log').on('click', () => {
  const url = $('.data-click.active').data('url') || 'Click an element first!';
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-url="1" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>
<a data-url="2" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>
<a data-url="3" href="#!" class="data-click">aaa</a>

<a href="#!" id="log">log</a>
```